# Generate a random image on front page each time it is loaded

Tags: media

I'd like to have a random image appear on the front page of my site each time the page is visited. Is there a module set up to do that? Any suggestions as to how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) Module to get the same. In the view all you need to make is a random query.